# Wordpress: Woocommerce without e-commerce for affiliate site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building an affiliate site and obviously for every product I use page not post. But pages don't have categories or tags and even if we add them to pages, our pages won't appear on categories' pages and in widget areas of front page.

Woocommerce functionality is perfect but it looks a little bit weird to use it for an affiliate site, not a store. Is it okay to delete e-commerce features (price, add to card and stuff like that) and use the rest of Woocommerce?

Comment: You can create a [Custom Post Type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/) called "Product" and give it taxonomy support (categories, tags, etc). That way you won't need to use WooCommerce and you can build your affiliate site exactly as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing weird to use Woocommerce without cart stuff. 
Sometimes clients want a catalog of goods, but not always need the cart and delivery staff on a site.
In this plugin it is much more comfortable to organize categories and editing of many products. Plus you get interaction with other plugins that build for Woocommerce.
If you make it thru "Custom Post Type", then it is normal if there are about 10.
If they are more, than you will need to create many solutions by yourself and you will have problems with their further maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is pretty good for e-commerce sites. As you creating affiliate site for that you can hide some functionality of Woocommerce. As you mention you want to hide (price, add to card and stuff like that). You have to use some actions to remove those functionality. Copy following code and place it in your active theme's function.php file.
**Note**: If you have child theme then you must have to add this code in child theme's function.php file.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','activate_filter') ; 
function activate_filter(){
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_cartBtn');
}

function hide_price_cartBtn(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
```

comment if you like to remove more things as you mention **stuff like that**